90's movie with a boy who walks the railing of a tower and almost falls
All I can remember is that I watched this movie on direct TV. The boy was ten or eleven. His best friend was a blonde girl who didn't know who her dad was. The boy was either an orphan or something because the man and woman he lived with were not his real parents.
At one point they are walking a long this grassy road. I think they are headed to church. At the end of the movie the boy climbs this tower, walks the railing and almost falls, but his new dad catches him. I'm pretty sure I watched this movie in the late 90's.

Country\language would really help here...

This sounds a lot like the French movie Le Grand Chemin (The Grand Highway) from 1987.

Louis, a nine-year-old boy from Paris, spends his summer vacation in a small town in Brittany. His mother Claire has lodged him with her girlfriend Marcelle and her husband Pelo while she's having her second baby. There Louis makes friends with Martine, the ten-year-old girl next door, and learns from her about life.

Louis hangs out a lot with the blonde Martine and near the end, Louis walks on the (church's?) roof and falls off. I'm almost sure Pelo catches him (he doesn't die, anyway). You can see Louis & Martine walking on the roof in the trailer near the end:



[The movie was remade in the US as Paradise (1991) with Melanie Griffith, Don Johnson, Elijah Wood and Thora Birch. It's possible you're after this instead, but I'm not sure it retained the roof scene.]
